# Proving that if $x^2\le 1$ then $x^2-7x\gt -10$

Tags: inequality

*Question:*

> Prove that if $x^2\le 1$ then $x^2-7x\gt  -10$

So I'm pretty new at proofs. I have a hard time with inequalities. I've been trying to do this using contrapostion.

If $x^2-7x\le-10$ then $x^2\gt 1$

Factoring $x^2-7x\le-10$

I get $(x-5)(x-2)\le 0$ which gives me $2\le x\le 5$.

I'm not sure where to go after that. I've tried applying the properties of inequalities but I have a hard time with that.

Comment: If $x^2\le1$, then $x^2-7x\le -7<-10$.  Simply note that since $0 \ge x^2\le 1$, then $-1\le x\le 1$.  And $\min(x^2-7x)\le \min(x^2)-7\max(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost done. If you have $2 \leq x \leq 5$ then isn't it clear that $x^2 > 1$?

By the way, I don't think proving the contrapositive made this any easier. Just start by factoring $x^2 \leq 1$ and deduce from there.

Comment: Hi thanks. The first time I did it I bounded x by -1 and 1 for x^2<=1. Then I plugged in  -1, 0 and 1. into x^2-7x>-10. The prof. said use the properties instead.

Comment: Would it be wrong to multiply each side by x to get 2x<=x^2<=5x then 2x<=5x. Then 2x^2<=5x^2. Which shows that 2x<2x^2 and 5x < 5x^2. which gives x<x2.

Comment: @HiPolyEraser why not just 1 < x therefore x < x^2?

Answer (score 0):

There is another way we can work, which does not use contraposition. We want to prove that:
$$\begin{array}[t]{l}x^2-7x+10 >0 \iff (x^2 -6x+9) - x+1 >0 \iff(x-3)^2-(x-1)>0\\
\end{array}.$$
Can you justify why the LHS of the last inequality is always positive (under the given assumptions)?